# Make this form send a php database query by setting Jquery Variables?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to convert jquery actions into variables that would eventually be sent off to a php query to search the database.
I'm thinking that some things such as text inputs can be stored as strings, while I'm unsure how I should treat checkboxes.
For example:
I have a checkbox such as 'please include all that interests you":
Beer
Wine
Sweets
Should I make each label a seperate TRUE/FALSE boolean in the database?
See my complete jsfiddle form and try to advise me (mind though,I'm a begginer in php,mysql and jquery :) )
Thank you everyone!

http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/TYT92/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json for store all option.
For example you can store your form in a json string and pass it with jquery ($.ajax)

```
{"hobbies": {"football": true,"cricket": false,"basket":true}}
```

try with http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/

and using json_encode and json_decode in php.

Answer (score 1):

You can store those checkboxes variables as tiny int or Boolean in the database Or you can store them in a single column (text) data type as json format like this [{"beer":0,"wine":1}] .and that's in case of increasing those options in the future and also you can use json_ encode  json_decode to convert array to json format in PHP